# CakePHP Unable to fetch belong to many data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have below tables

```
service_categories
users
users_service_categories
```

I have created below relation in UsersTable

```
$this->belongsToMany('ServiceCategories',[
      'foreignkey' => 'user_id',
      'targetForeignKey' => 'service_category_id',
      'joinTable' => 'users_service_categories',
]);
```

Belong to many data are saving perfectly

[image]

In controller index method I have written below query

```
$users = $this->Users->find('all')
          ->contain(['UserTypes', 'ServiceCategories']);
```

I am getting only service category id not service category associative data,

[image]

For id 3 and 6 data in service categories

[image]

Query that I am getting in debug sql log

[image]

How I will get the service categories details here ?

Comment: Obligatory dumb question: service categories with IDs 3 and 6 exist? I see that they're in the join table, but in the actual service categories table?

Comment: 3 and 6 are exist in service_categories table.

Comment: Looks to me like it should work. If you run that query manually, do you get expected results?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I got my desire output in view page , for individual user. But not in index page for all users.

Comment: It's rather unlikely that entity objects are completely empty, as they have many default properties and values. Empty objects (unless they truly have no dumpable properties/values), are usually references, as the debugger will only dump one and the same object once to avoid recursion, duplicates will be shown as empty (but usually with `id:n` as a link to the fully dumped object in the output). Expand all your users to check whether the same entities might be present somewhere else. Also try dumping `$users->toArray()` instead of the result set object.